# Is there a way I can check multiple condition with one 'matches' function?

Tags: java, string

Consider the following statement :

```
if(UserAgent.matches("iPhone"))
```

I have to detect whether the user is online from a mobile or a PC. To do this I need to check for large number mobile devices,browsers. Instead of writing the same part :

```
if(UserAgent.matches())
```

Is there any way I can check this using on `matches` function ? I meant to say by using `|` which is OR. Like :

```
UserAgent.matches(SOME MODIFICATION "iPhone" | "Android" | "Blackberry".....)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, String.matches() is matching as a Regular Expression, so you may write something like

```
if (UserAgent.matches("iPhone|Android|Blackberry"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all strings in a Set, then check if the UserAgent string is contained in that set.

```
if set.contains(UserAgent.toString())
    // do something
end
```